# ASP.NET Core (.Net 6) Web Application throws System.NotSupportedException when run as a service. (Service will not start)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-services, .net-6.0

When I attempt to run my .Net Web Application as a Windows Service, it does not start. It works if I just run the executable but mysteriously fails when attempting to run as a service. I have logged the relevant error messages and reported my solution below.

The following exception is in the event viewer.

#### Exception in Event Viewer

> Application: WebApplication5.exe
> CoreCLR Version: 6.0.222.6406
> .NET Version: 6.0.2
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
> Exception Info: System.NotSupportedException: The content root changed from "C:\Windows\system32" to "C:\Program Files (x86)\My Company\webapp5". Changing the host configuration using WebApplicationBuilder.Host is not supported. Use WebApplication.CreateBuilder(WebApplicationOptions) instead.
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ConfigureHostBuilder.ConfigureHostConfiguration(Action`1 configureDelegate) at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingHostBuilderExtensions.UseContentRoot(IHostBuilder hostBuilder, String contentRoot) at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServiceLifetimeHostBuilderExtensions.UseWindowsService(IHostBuilder hostBuilder, Action`1 configure)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServiceLifetimeHostBuilderExtensions.UseWindowsService(IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
> at Program.$(String[] args) in C:\Users\Jonathan\source\repos\WebApplication5\WebApplication5\Program.cs:line 10

### Steps to Recreate

#### Program.cs

My application is based on the *ASP.NET Core Web API* template. I followed instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#app-configuration and added `UseWindowsService()` to `Program.cs`

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Host.UseWindowsService();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

#### Deploy binary and create a service

I compile a binary with `dotnet publish -c Debug --self-contained --runtime win-x64 -p:PublishSingleFile=true`

Copy the output to the target machine and run in an Administrative Powershell

```
New-Service -Name WebApplication5 -BinaryPathName C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Desktop\webapp5\WebApplication5.exe
```

#### When I attempt to start the service:

```
    PS C:> Start-Service WebApp5
    Start-Service : Service 'WebApp5 (WebApp5)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot start service WebApp5 on computer '.'.
    At line:1 char:1
    + Start-Service WebApp5
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotStartService,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

When I use the Services GUI:

> Windows could not start the WebApplication5 service on Local Computer
>
> Error 1053:The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like the exception in event-viewer suggests, I needed to use a non-default constructor in `Program.cs` and set the `ContentRootPath` there.

Change this default constructor:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

Change to:

```
var webApplicationOptions = new WebApplicationOptions
{
    ContentRootPath = AppContext.BaseDirectory,
    Args = args,
};    
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(webApplicationOptions);
```

Here's the rest of my `program.cs` for reference:

```
//set ContentRootPath so that builder.Host.UseWindowsService() doesn't crash when running as a service
var webApplicationOptions = new WebApplicationOptions
{
    ContentRootPath = AppContext.BaseDirectory,
    Args = args,
};    
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(webApplicationOptions);

//All the following code is unchanged from my original program.cs

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Host.UseWindowsService();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Thankyou.  Ive been trying to get to the bottom of this for the last hour! Your answer did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Works like a charm! Thanks.

one more line added to setup the url:

```
builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://localhost:" + _portNo);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31741022)